# unable to connect to local sql server database after SharePoint is installed

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sharepoint-2010

I had a local database used to connect with sql server authentication, every thing was perfectly working. i installed share point server 2010 standalone version in the machine and it created new sql server instance for SharePoint data and am able to connect to new share point instance.

The problem is now after installing SharePoint, i am unable to connect to the local database i was previously connecting without any problem.
[image]
please help me

Thanks,

Pradeep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is resolved, After share point install the somehow the sql server services was stopped and i started the service and again it is running without any problem.

Thanks,
Pradeep